# Scala - Rule to infer the variable on the right hand side

Tags: scala

I tried to do research but still not yet figure out what is the terminology of Scala, related to lower case a,b as per the code below

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = a => b => f(a, b)
```

Why is that a,b appears on the right hand side?

I know that it is a part of Algebraic Data Type but still could not find a match definition for this.

**Update based on Tim's answer**, "Scala knows the type of a and b from the return type A => (B => C). a is type A, b is type B."

I want to ask about how Scala knows the type of a and b, i.e: the mechanism behind? What is the terminology of this?

I guess this is a language feature. Please suggest a foundation guideline to fully understand and practice to gain intuition when  reading these complex code.

**Update from Mario Galic's comment**: ... *Scala compiler can perform type inference based on the signature of curry* ... Please clarify: if the left hand side (i.e the signature) is too obvious, why we need to have the right hand side definition? I mean, there is only 1 way to infer the logic of the left hand side, then, what is the need of creating the right hand side content?

P/S: I wish that I could mark each feedback as the answer because each provides different aspect which helps me to fully grasp the meaning.

Comment: The question does not make sense. Please phrase it differently so we can understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/anonymous-functions.html https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expression-in-scala/

Comment: Although each answer is valuable, I marked jwvh's feedback as answer because he provided the relationship from instance "function" to trait Function1. There is still 1 last item has not been addressed, which I updated, i.e " if there is only 1 way to infer the logic of the left hand side, then, what is the need of creating the right hand side content?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we all know, it's pretty easy to create a tuple: `(1,'a')`. And the type of said tuple is pretty simple: `(Int,Char)`. That type designation, however, is a convenient alternative for the more verbose type designation `Tuple2[Int,Char]`. In fact, the  tuple creation itself is a convenient alternate syntax to the more direct `new Tuple2(1,'a')`.

It's a similar story with functions.

The type designation `Char => Int` is a convenient alternative to the more verbose `Function1[Char,Int]`. And, after studying the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/Function1.html), we learn that a simple function like...

```
val ctoi = (c:Char) => c.toInt
```

...is the equivalent of...

```
val ctoi = new Function1[Char, Int] {
  def apply(c: Char): Int = c.toInt
}
```

So, armed with this information, we can now translate...

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) =
  a => b => f(a, b)
```

...into its equivalent...

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: Function2[A,B,C]): Function1[A,Function1[B,C]] =
  new Function1[A,Function1[B,C]] {
    def apply(a:A) = new Function1[B,C] {def apply(b:B) = f(a,b)}
  }
```

With this it's a little easier to see how `a => b => ...`, while a bit confusing at first, is actually a very convenient way to designate the names of the arguments being passed in to the hidden `apply()` methods.

Comment: Thank you @jwvh for your feedback. Yes, Function1 is itself a trait, and it is like a generic class in Java, which brought up another technique which I'm also trying to figure out. The way Function1 (or event FunctionN) was created is like an implementation based on language feature (Scala in this case), rather than the language itself.
Why is that a Function1 turns out to be originally a trait? Why a function cannot be itself a function but to be initialized from a trait?

Comment: Because, from that fact, a function is now need another function (i.e: which is the call to constructor via: new Function1...) to be created, which is actually a Factory concept, in which we need a Factory to manufacture the operable function. And from which, Function1 is an abstraction, then why does it need to be from the core of Scala. Instead, it is a library rather than a core feature of this language.

Comment: One of the principal tenants of Functional Programming is that functions are first class values. That means that a function can return a function as its return value, and a function can be passed as an argument to another function, just like we can do with a `List`, or a `Tuple`, or an `Option`. So it makes a certain amount of sense that we should construct a `Function` the same way we do for a `List` or a `Tuple` or an `Option`, i.e. as an instance of a class (or trait).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. to me, the knowledge within the content you provided and Jim McBeath's "Scala Functions vs Methods" should be the beginning lesson for those who begin to learn Scala (of course after knowing basic OOP like Class, instance, object, method...). It is strange that none book or tutorial about Scala provide such systematically explanation; rather than they jump into define and use function which is providing confusion after confusion.

Comment: By the way @jwvh , this is more than the scope of the question, but because mentioned about it, please tell the meaning of "functions are first class values"
Because, from that statement, I would think that "Class comes first", then "function comes later", so that, it would be better to specify clearly that "in Scala all functions are instance of class"

Comment: "functions are first class values", or, at some other sources, they mentioned that "Functions are first-class citizens". This statement does not tell about the nature of Scala's function, instead, it is more like "how we can treat a function".

Comment: "First class citizens/values" means that functions hold equal status with all other value types and objects. It simply means that functions aren't "different." Once a function is instantiated it can be handled (passed around) like any other value instance.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to add full type annotations

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = 
  (a: A) => ((b: B) => f(a, b): C)
```

Note how `curry` is a method that takes a function as input and also returns a function as output. You might be wondering where do `a` and `b` come from in the output function

```
(a: A) => ((b: B) => f(a, b): C)
```

but note that they are just the means of declaring the parameters of the output function. You are free to give them any name, for example the following would also work

```
(x: A) => ((y: B) => f(x, y): C)
```

The key is to understand that functions are first class values in Scala, so you can pass them in as arguments to other functions and return them as return values from other functions, in the same way you would do with familiar values like say integer `42`. Writing value `42` is straightforward, but writing down function value is more verbose since you have to specify the parameters like `a` and `b` but nevertheless conceptually it is still just a value. Hence we could say `curry` is a method that takes a value and returns a value, but these values happen to be function values.

Comment: Thank you Mario Galic. As per your answer, "You you can pass them in as arguments to other functions", I understood about this, I just don't know why there is a,b appear without declaration, and the terminology of this Scala technique

Comment: @datnt The reason why you can omit type annotations of `a` and `b` function parameters is because Scala compiler can perform type inference based on the signature of `curry`, in particular based on the return function type `A => (B => C)`.

Comment: Thank you @Mario Galic. I updated the question from your feedback, please provide more insight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't really make sense, but in case this helps here is a breakdown of that line:

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = a => b => f(a, b)
```

This splits into a definition and an implementation with `=` inbetween. The definition is

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C)
```

Breaking it down further, `A`, `B`, and `C` are type parameters, meaning that any three types can be used when calling this function.

Next comes the single argument to the function:

```
f: (A, B) => C
```

The value of this argument is a function that takes two values (one of type `A` and one of type `B`) are returns a single value of type `C`.

Next comes the type of the result:

```
 A => (B => C)
```

This is a function that takes a single argument of type `A` and returns a function that takes a single argument of type `B` and returns a result of type `C`.

So `curry` is a function that takes a function of type `(A, B) => C`) and returns a function of type `A => (B => C)`. This implements the process known as currying (hence the name).

Now for the implementation (the other side of the `=`):

```
a => b => f(a, b)
```

Adding some brackets might make this clearer:

```
a => (b => f(a, b))
```

This is a function that take `a` and returns `b => f(a, b)`. `a` is the argument for this function. So that leaves this

```
b => f(a, b)
```

This is a simple function with an argument `b` that returns `f(a, b)`.

Scala knows the type of `a` and `b` from the return type `A => (B => C)`. `a` is type `A`, `b` is type `B`.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I updated the question to provide more specific detail.